# Does Magento handles huge product catalog volume?

Tags: magento, search, nginx, indexing, sphinx

I am having Magento CE 1.9 website with 135,000 products, 2500 categories and 8 stores. I have installed Sphinx search for fast searching product catalog and have Nginx server. Also i have full page cache extension installed in it. But still my website is very slow and indexing is killing our time.

Please advise on configuration and solution for indexing.

Especially search indexing is taking more time for my website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your main concern (1) slow site or (2) slow indexing or(3)slow search ?

Comment: First Concern is slow indexing.

Comment: What are you indexing exactly? We use Sphinx on very large websites and indexing of about 100k records (with lots of content in each record) takes a few minutes. Also, what are your server specs?

Comment: Right now we are using  Build in sphinx search engine configuration. Search indexing is taking more than 5 days and still it is asking for "re-index required". Server Specification: Nginx web server, Amazon EC2 instance - C3 2Xlarge, Magento 1.9 CE, Amazon RDS database.

Comment: I am assuming you are using "Advanced Sphinx Search Pro", correct? If that is so you have to ask support at Mirasvit. We have had exactly the same issue. Because when you are installing the extension it overwrites the default indexer. The guys at Mirasvit are very proffesional and fast with responses. In your case they will ask for access to the Magento BE and SSH. Hope this helps you!